# How to tell Twisted http server to ignore index files

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.web

I am serving a local directory with Twisted http server as:

```
from twisted.web.server import Site
from twisted.web.static import File
from twisted.internet import reactor, endpoints

resource = File('./')
factory = Site(resource)
reactor.listenTCP(8888,factory)
reactor.run()
```

The server serves the specified directory properly. But, when there is any index file (index, index.html) in a directory, then the server displays that index file, instead of serving the local directory.
So, how do I tell Twisted server to ignore the index files and continue to serve the local directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`twisted.web.static.File` uses `self.indexNames` to determine which files are considered index files.  You can override this value to change the behavior.

```py
from twisted.web.server import Site
from twisted.web.static import File
from twisted.internet import reactor, endpoints

resource = File('./')
resource.indexNames = []
factory = Site(resource)
reactor.listenTCP(8888,factory)
reactor.run()
```